# A variable references bug?

Tags: php

I have a cannot understand problem, the following code why is print  Array ( [a] => 1 [b] => 2 [c] => 3 [d] => ) , I didn't change the $info variable but why it changed?

```
<?php
function ifSetOr(&$a, $b = null) {
    return isset($a) ? $a : $b;
}

$info = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3);
ifSetOr($info['d']);
print_r($info); //Array ( [a] => 1 [b] => 2 [c] => 3 [d] => ) 
?>
```

Comment: Well, you tried to access `$info['d']` and pass a reference to it to a function. Since it does not exist and therefore cannot be referenced, PHP created it automatically. At least that would be my guess. Note that `isset` is not a function, it is a language construct and works differently than functions.

Answer (score 3):

You implicitly created `$info['d']` when you passed it as a reference.

For this reason a ifSetOr function like that can never work. You cannot pass around nonexisting variables. Also keep in mind that "parameters" for `isset` are an exception because `isset` is not really a function but a language construct.

Comment: How can I avoid this problem ?

Comment: @joe: The only alternative I see is pass the array and the name of the key to the function and to `return isset $a[$key] ...`.

Comment: Is not there a better solution ?

Comment: counter question: do you really need this for other things than array elements? If so, your code might need other improvement first.